# Converting a List<Long> to comma separated string

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-stringutils

Hi I am having a requirement where I need to convert `List` of `Long` datatype to comma separated `String`. 
Which would be the appropriate way. I have thought about using string builder or converting it to `List<String>` and then using `StringUtils` join to get a `String`.

I am looking for `java 7` solution,Not using `guava` or `java 8`.

Comment: I have tried converting it to list of string and using string utils.join . But i am not sure is this the right way,

Comment: Okay, that duplicate was about `List<String>`, not `List<Long>`, but most answers should still apply. Reopen if not.

Comment: can you refer this, list.toString()

Comment: i have tried TextUtils.join(",", urlist<Long>); and worked for me

Comment: What bout this approach:                                                                             
String collect = listLong.stream().map(x->String.valueOf(x)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));   listLong is reference for List<Long>

Answer (score 36):

You can try this:

```
StringUtils.join(mylist, ',');
```

See [org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join-long:A-char-).

Comment: That also works with `List<Long>`. The method takes an `Iterable<?>`

Comment: I was under wrong assumption that it will work only for List of String Data Types, Thanks

Comment: @JordiCastilla - I know. But I presume that some *other* people who will be viewing this answer might be using java -8 :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar: and these other people will soon find out that StringJoiner does not work with `List<Long>`.

Comment: @Thilo - Ya, they will have to cast longs to strings in some way. Hmm.. Probably not worth mentioning it at all then

Comment: It prepended separator when used on Set<Long>

Comment: issue I am facing is , values IN ( ? ) , It should prepare (v1,v2) but it creates ('v1,v2')  , any alternative solutions ?

Comment: It worked with org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils import, but NOT with com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils.